# Does python -c '...' or exec(...) create temporary files?

Tags: python

Where are temporary files saved when running the commands or are there no temporary files created?

```
python -c "print('Hello, World!')"
```

and

```
exec("print('Hello, World!')")
```

Both Windows and macOS. Does Python run directly or is it compiled into a temporary file and then run?

I use Google Translate.

Comment: By the way -- in general, Stack Overflow is only for "actual problems that you face", as described in https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. If you don't have a practical concern _caused by_ temporary files (and since they don't exist, you _can't_ have such a concern) -- how is it a problem you face?

Comment: ...it's a pretty good rule-of-thumb that languages that offer a REPL as a core feature can interpret code without writing any intermediate content to disk.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Although the rules say that, it is not how Stack Overflow is used at all. Example: [tag:language-lawyer]. The question _as is_, is completely fine. OP doesn't need to have a problem to ask such a question.

Comment: @Marco, different tags have different conventions -- as I'm sure you're well-aware. What's acceptable in language-lawyer isn't acceptable everywhere.

Comment: I think this question is completely fine even if it did not have practical use, but there might be practical uses for running python without creating temporary files.

Comment: @NikoFohr, I agree that there are practical uses for running Python without creating temporary files, but the question _isn't_ "how can I run Python without creating temporary files?". If it were, and the OP were having a specific practical problem attempting to do so, I would have no qualm whatsoever.

Comment: Well at least this will be the top of Google search results if someone wants to run python without creating temporary files and is first thinking about using `python -c "some code"` and wants to verify the idea :)

Comment: @Marco, btw, I also tend to consider language lawyering to be an inherently practical concern: if you don't understand the specification you can't be sure you're writing code that future compilers wil interpret correctly so long as they're spec-compliant. That understanding, then, is intended to change how one goes about the _practice_ of software development.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy So what? The same can be applied to this very question. _"Does python -c create temporary files?"_ can be seen as a "practical concern" too.

Comment: @Charles Duffy: I want to share a python program but not the source code form. And I'm considering this. Exclude encryption methods using pyinstaller or cython, etc. I don't understand how the above two commands work and can't find any results, so I hope someone can help answer them.

Comment: @StackUser That's your _broader_ context and yes, you should include that in your question if it is relevant (in this case, it is). Generally speaking, it is _very_ hard to protect source code that is ran by an interpreter. On some systems, you might be easily able to capture the `python -c` call _anyway_. Same applies for compiled programs, although the effort is considerably higher with those. Bottom line: the computer you give the executable to somehow must be able to read and execute your code so making it "completely secret" is inherently not possible.

Comment: @Marco I get it. I will add to the question. So can you show me where to save temporary shell files on windows when running the above command?

Comment: @StackUser Since your question will be _completely_ different from the question you have asked here, you should follow the procedure to open a new question. Especially since this question has already been answered.

Comment: @Marco I get it.

Comment: **Don't** edit this question, ask a new one if it already has not been asked here before.

Comment: pyinstaller isn't actually very effective at hiding your source code -- I say this as the author of [pydeinstaller](https://github.com/charles-dyfis-net/pydeinstaller) (which granted doesn't work anymore, but one can still get bytecode back out and read it by hand easily enough). _In general_, my answer for folks asking this question is to the effect of "there are no options that work against a motivated and capable attacker who controls the hardware your software is run on".

Comment: ...that being the case, in some cases the solution is to bring "the hardware your software is run on" into your own control -- offloading some critical algorithm to a web service, f/e, and being very careful about exactly how you secure that service.

Comment: @Marco I edit with info question. Not ask the second problem.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I get it. I'm just looking for another way.

Comment: Historical answered questions about your "real" use case: [How do I protect Python code from being read by users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261638/how-do-i-protect-python-code-from-being-read-by-users), [protect python code from reverse engineering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41633039/protect-python-code-from-reverse-engineering), [How to prevent decompilation or inspecting Python code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390489/how-to-prevent-decompilation-or-inspecting-python-code)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy In this case, the user doesn't want to put the data on the web so I can't provide the website.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I learned this way before trying the above two commands. Back to the point, did you know the shell temporarily saves the file when running the above command? I looked in temp on Windows, user folder. But no thing.

Comment: A lot of details go outside of the scope of a reasonable Stack Overflow question. What's the budget and revenue model? How many users do you have? It's an available option to ship and run your code on a USB dongle (with the CPU on the dongle emulating an ethernet device f/e) if the revenue model supports it, and that way it doesn't have to be installed onto the user's computer at all.

Comment: Again, it's only the `<<EOF` heredoc usage that causes the shell to create a temporary file. If you aren't using a heredoc, there's no such file.

Comment: Thank you both. Maybe I basically have the answer to this problem.

Comment: For what it's worth -- you'll get slightly better security using `exec()` after decrypting the content when you're already in a Python interpreter than you would when using `python -c '...'` to pass previously-decrypted code, since process listings are effectively public. Even then, though, _slightly better_ security is not the same as _good_ security.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, neither of these operations creates any temporary file. Python creates `.pyc` files only as a performance optimization to speed future loading of the same code, and works perfectly well without them.

This is typical behavior for interpreted languages as opposed to compiled ones. As Python is generally compiled only to bytecode and not to native executables (even tools that create native executables from Python generally pack an interpreter and source code or bytecode for it to work on into that executable, instead of properly compiling to native CPU instructions); and as that bytecode can be interpreted in-process by the same tool that compiles Python source *into* said bytecode, Python is for this purpose effectively interpreted. (There's a larger discussion of the semantics at [Is Python interpreted, or compiled, or both?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6889747/is-python-interpreted-or-compiled-or-both), but the definition doesn't really matter for practical purposes so I'm not going to go into it further here).

---

What *would* create a temporary file (with most but not all shells) is:

```
python <<EOF
print("Hello, world!")
EOF
```

...but in that case the file is created by the shell, not by Python itself.

Comment: I get it. So where does the shell save these temporary files? For example: cmd on Windows.

Comment: @StackUser, typically your operating system will have an environment variable that defines where temporary files go -- I believe that's `TEMP` on Windows, `TMPDIR` on UNIXy systems. That said, the `<<EOF` heredoc syntax is more a UNIXy thing; I don't know offhand if cmd.exe has an equivalent.

Comment: @StackUser Follow up questions should be posted separately. Of course only if they haven't been asked before here.

Comment: @Charles Duffy: I try find everywhere in Windows before ask.
Marco: I get it. I didn't expect the question to be answered so soon.